# Certain localhost PDF file found but cannot be viewed by Chrome

Tags: php, html

Why Chrome cannot view a certain PDF file from localhost, while it can view other PDFs.

In addition, the PDF file that cannot be viewed by Chrome, it can be viewed by Mozilla firefox.

Plese find below, the screen shot of when the PDF file could not be viewed.

Thank you,

Andy.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Can you share the PDF?

Comment: You need to give alot more details. What does the PDF include? Have you tested other browsers? Or maybe different versions of Chrome? Upload it somewhere online, and then visit browsershots.org and see if it shows in certain Chrome versions.

Comment: Please find the following link http://danonenutrindo.org/pdf/NewsletterDec09.pdf. My Google Crhome version is the latest Version 40.0.2214.115 m. Please try with Mozilla firefox, it will have no problem.